# Javascript Sort by Object Value that has Multiple Meanings (group) with only Comparartor

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have some data formatted like so:

```
var data = [
        { id: 1, name:  "Netherlands", population: 17},
        { id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4},
        { id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2},
        { id: 2, name:  "USA", population: 350},
        { id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55},
        { id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4},
        { id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgard", population: 3},
        { id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3},
        { id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60},
        { id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30},
        { id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2},
    ];
```

Basically name can be either city or country. Countries are identified as whole numbers and their cities as .1. Each country can have 0-3 cities.

Is it possible to write a comparator function for Array.prototype.sort where it sorts for instance, the countries alphabetically, then by their cities but keeps the country/city grouping intact, and does not mutate the data array beforehand? Is this possible? If not, why? If it is not possible, I'd still be interested to know how to do this mutating the array beforehand, though it will require a lot more backtracking for me, and is not ideal.

So sorting alphabetically by name would give:

```
var data = [
    { id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30},
    { id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2},
    { id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55},
    { id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4},
    { id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3},
    { id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgard", population: 3},
    { id: 1, name:  "Netherlands", population: 17},
    { id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2},
    { id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4},
    { id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60},
    { id: 2, name:  "USA", population: 350},
];
```

Here is a plunker, with how far I have gotten:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vPTaoh

I don't understand why/how array.prototype.sort picks which values to compare, so I'm not sure what direction to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The data structure you've chosen will make it pretty messy and inefficient to do it.

Comment: Array#sort [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: FYI I'm working on a solution that needs pre-manipulation or processing. It ain't gonna be pretty, though...

Comment: Nevermind. They've got there before me. ^^

Comment: @Whothehellisthat you might still want to post an answer that constructs an external city->countryname lookup table without mutating the array items, so that we get all solutions :-)

Comment: I think torazaburo covered that in his edit?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why/how `Array.prototype.sort` picks which values to compare

It picks them arbitrarily from the array, depending on what sorting algorithm it uses internally. Your comparison function needs to work on all values.

> Is it possible to write a comparator function for `Array.prototype.sort` where it sorts for instance, the countries alphabetically, then by their cities but keeps the country/city grouping intact, and does not mutate the data array beforehand?

No, this is not (easily) possible. To compare two items, you always need to compare their countries first, but that's not possible whent the item is a city: there is no link from the city to the country name.
You would need to find a way to look this up first (technically it's possible given the `id`, but you have to construct a lookup table beforehand or inefficiently search the array during sorting).

You would do yourself a favour by changing your data to the following structure:

```
var data = [
    {id: 1, name:  "Netherlands", population: 17, cities: [
        {id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4},
        {id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2}
    ]},
    {id: 2, name: "USA", population: 350, cities: []},
    {id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55, cities: [
        {id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4},
        {id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgard", population: 3},
        {id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3}
    ]},
    {id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60, cities: []},
    {id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30, cities: [
        {id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2}
    ]}
];
```

And then simply sort the countries only and the cities within them using the standard approach.

Comment: But he also wants to sort cities within countries; you've cheated by presorting them.

Comment: @torazaburo Does he? Oh, `data.forEach(c => c.cities.sort(byName))` does that. I didn't even pre-sort them, I kept the order from the question.

Comment: @torazaburo wait, I just copied the wrong array. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.sort` picks any values it needs to to compare, so you have to be prepared to return the ordering for e.g. 3.1 vs. 1.2, which will require looking up the country name.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const countryAName = array.find(elt => elt.id === countryA).name;
  const countryBName = array.find(elt => elt.id === countryB).name;

  return countryAName < countryBName ? -1 :
    countryAName > countryBName ? +1 :
    a.name < b.name ? -1 :
    a.name > b.name ? +1 : 0;
}
```

As Bergi correctly points out, the `array.find` in the comparator is going to be pretty inefficient. So you might want to preprocess the array to include the country in each item in the array:

```
array.forEach(elt => elt.country = array.find(e => e.id === Math.floor(elt.id)).name);
```

Then you can write the comparator as:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  return a.country < b.country ? -1 :
    a.country > b.country ? +1 :
    a.name < b.name ? -1 :
    a.name > b.name ? +1 : 0;
}
```

If you would prefer not to "mutate" the array by adding the `country` property to each element, then you could put it in a separate lookup table:

```
const map = [];
array.forEach(elt => { if (!(elt.id % 1)) map[Math.floor(elt.id)] = elt.name; });
```

Then write the comparator as

```
function compare(a, b) {
  const countryAName = map[Math.floor(a.id)];
  const countryBName = map[Math.floor(b.id)];

 return countryAName < countryBName ? -1 :
    countryAName > countryBName ? +1 :
    a.name < b.name ? -1 :
    a.name > b.name ? +1 : 0;

}
```

Comment: Ah, exactly what I meant by "inefficient solution" and "lookup" in my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, though this doesn't internally sort the cities as well? See my updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vPTaoh How would you do that like the output in my question?

Comment: Sorry, missed that you wanted to sort cities alphabetically too, now fixed.

Comment: Hmmm, now it's giving an unexpected result. Not sure whats wrong. new plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8K6uE2

Comment: @AnotherMike Good call! If the `countryName`s are the same, you must not only compare by name, but first make sure to sort the country before the cities. So add a `a.id == Math.floor(b.id) ? -1 : Math.floor(a.id) == b.id ? +1 :` in the midst to [make it work](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZvPBMvJZ4WfSkbJLl37G)

Comment: @torazaburo btw, Redu has found out in his answer below that one shouldn't call `.find` during the sorting on the array, so you'd need to make a copy of that

Comment: @Bergi can you throw together a working example when you have a chance, I'm a bit confused, would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Bergi, oh my bad, sorry it's been a long day! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table for the country name object and some calculation for moving the country up.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Netherlands", population: 17 }, { id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4 }, { id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2 }, { id: 2, name: "USA", population: 350 }, { id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55 }, { id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4 }, { id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgart", population: 3 }, { id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3 }, { id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60 }, { id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30 }, { id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2 }, ],
    hash = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.id === Math.floor(a.id)) {
        hash[a.id] = a.name;
    }
});

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getHash(o) { return hash[Math.floor(o.id)]; }

    return (
        getHash(a).localeCompare(getHash(b)) ||                      // compare country
        (Math.floor(a.id) !== a.id) - (Math.floor(b.id) !== b.id) || // move int to top
        a.name.localeCompare(b.name)                                 // compare city
    );
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any hash this code works perfectly well on FF but cracks Chrome (or any recent WebKit browser like Opera) for no reason that i can think of. It's been already late and i have spent last hour desperately checking types or so without any luck. I would love if somebody could point out what's going wrong in Chrome?

```js
var data = [
        { id: 1, name:  "Netherlands", population: 17},
        { id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4},
        { id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2},
        { id: 2, name:  "USA", population: 350},
        { id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55},
        { id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4},
        { id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgard", population: 3},
        { id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3},
        { id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60},
        { id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30},
        { id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2},
    ],
  sorted = data.sort((a,b) => a.id%1 === 0 && b.id%1 === 0 ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
                                                           : ~~a.id === ~~b.id ? a.id - b.id
                                                                               : data.find(o => o.id === ~~a.id).name.localeCompare(data.find(o => o.id === ~~b.id).name));
console.log(sorted);
```

Well interesting really.. As per @Bergi's comment i did `try` & `catch` @ Chrome and logged the data array when the error is caught. However once the error is swallowed by `catch` it returned the result perfectly though. Check this up on Chrome.

```js
var data = [
        { id: 1, name:  "Netherlands", population: 17},
        { id: 1.1, name: "Rotterdam", population: 4},
        { id: 1.2, name: "Amsterdam", population: 2},
        { id: 2, name:  "USA", population: 350},
        { id: 3, name: "Germany", population: 55},
        { id: 3.1, name: "Berlin", population: 4},
        { id: 3.2, name: "Stuttgard", population: 3},
        { id: 3.3, name: "Cologne", population: 3},
        { id: 4, name: "UK", population: 60},
        { id: 5, name: "Canada", population: 30},
        { id: 5.1, name: "Ottawa", population: 2},
    ],
  sorted = data.sort(function(a,b){
                       try {
                             return a.id%1 === 0 && b.id%1 === 0 ? a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
                                                                 : ~~a.id === ~~b.id ? a.id - b.id
                                                                                     : data.find(o => o.id === ~~a.id).name.localeCompare(data.find(o => o.id === ~~b.id).name);
                       }
                       catch(e) {console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) }
                     });
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: What exactly is "wrong"? Notice that you are sorting cities by their id, not by their name.

Comment: @Bergi It's sorting fine with FF (first priority is to sort cities by `name` if the `id` is integer, second priority sort by non floored ids if floored `id`s are equal and third priority is to find master city name from master `id` and sort accordingly. It's ok in FF but won't like `data.find(o => o.id === ~~b.id).name` after a few iterations in Chrome.

Comment: You mean it throws a "*cannot access property `.name` of `undefined`*" in Chrome?

Comment: That's interesting… But I don't think there is anything wrong with Chrome. The spec doesn't mandate that all elements are in the array during a call to the compare function. Can you do a  `try { … } catch(e) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) }` to confirm this? I guess there should be a golden rule "don't access the array you're sorting from the comparison function" just like the "don't call `splice` on an array you are currently iterating".

Comment: @Bergi Wow.. when i did `try` & `catch` and once the error (two errors i suppose) are swallowed by `catch` it worked..?!? See above...

Comment: Yeah, because the `undefined` it returns from the `catch` block will lead to an arbitrary (and in this case, luckily correct) order. But what logs did you get for the JSON?

Comment: @Bergi Well yes... we receive two errors. When i first noticed this I had discovered that it was getting stuck at `id: 4` and now the logs prove that at the time of the error there is infact no `id: 4` in the array but instead there is a duplicate of `id: 1` hence searching for `id: 4` returns `"undefined"`. And in the second error this time `id: 1` disappears and there are two `id: 1.1` s. I guess with Chrome's sorting algorithm we can not access the source array reliably. If you have Chrome you can run the second snippet and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that what I wanted to hear. I don't have a Chrome available right now, so I could only guess :-)